# Manipulating Time Series data in Google-cloud library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-python

I am trying to get data from a custom Stackdriver metric using the Google-Cloud Python library, but beyond returning it as a pandas dataframe I can't get the values I need.

For example the query, which looks something like:

```
query = client.query(metric_type, minutes=5)
```

which when using pandas returns something like this:

```
resource_type                                 l7_lb_rule
project_id                                    my_id
backend_name
backend_zone
forwarding_rule_name                          foo-http     foo-https
instance_group_name
matched_url_path_rule
target_proxy_name                           foo-target-1 foo-https-060417
target_proxy_type
url_map_name                                         foo              foo
log                                             requests         requests
2017-06-26 15:43:06.750                               26               25
```

Yet I'm not sure how to manipulate this to get the values I need, which essentially are the number of http and https requests (I want to sum these).

For example if I were to use `iterrows()` how could I filter this down so it shows me the data I need?

Or perhaps displaying it as a dataframe isn't how I should be doing it, I just can't see how else to get this data using this library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just wanna see the data, you should use Cloud Console since it has some great ways to filter data. If you are doing processing on logs, I would suggest using sinks to write them to bigquery and then query and load data from bigquery into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to avoid using dataframes entirely and just iterate over the timeseries object to extract the values I need.